# cosine and sine value of large numbers VHDl

Tags: module, vhdl, xilinx, trigonometry

I want to implement a CPM modulation in VHDL and my device is Spartan 3A DSP. After the mathematical operation the provided data is the argument for a trigonometric functions and i'm trying to use CORDIC IP CORE in Xilinx 14.7 for this and the problem is that the input data for CORDIC must place between -pi to pi and i don't know how to do this that it could be synthetizable! for now i'm trying to implement the modulation in base band and only the cosine and sine value of the provided data should be send. for example i need the value of "cosine(234.56)" but i don't know how to do it!! i would appreciate if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: One solution is to implement sine/cosine functions as a lookup table in BlockRAM. Normally the value is not stored as floating point numbers nor is it stored in the requested range. The trick is to scale and move input and intermediate values so numbers from [-PI .. PI] fit in the range of binary numbers; can be mapped to memory addresses and avoid floating point operations (best case: integer operations; medium case: fixed point operations). A simple sine/cosine lookup table can be found here: [PoC.mem.lut.sine](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/lut/lut_Sine.vhdl)

Comment: You should probably start by reading carefully the documentation of this CORDIC IP core to understand how the input and output data are represented. I never used it but I guess they are represented in a kind of fixed point format (a given number of bits on the left and on the right of the binary point). It could also be that the position of the binary point is specified by a dedicated other input. In this case you would have a kind of floating point representation. And last but not least, pay attention to the scale (degrees, radians, other) and to the sign (signed or unsigned).

Comment: @Paebbels Is there a way to subtract the 2Pi multiples from large numbers here?